# When in Japan can I obtain a B-1/B-2 visa to go to USA for a short personal trip?

Tags: usa, japan, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, business-travel

I am going on a business visa to Japan.

Comment: btw I am an Indian national

Comment: No you cannot. You need to apply from India.

Answer (score 7):

From http://japan.usembassy.gov/e/visa/tvisa-nivgeneralfaq.html

> **May I apply for a US visa when I’m just visiting Japan?**
>
> Applicants for visas to the United States should generally apply at
>   the American Embassy or Consulate with jurisdiction over their place
>   of permanent residence. Non-immigrant visa applicants who are resident
>   in Japan must demonstrate compelling social, economic, and
>   professional ties to Japan in order to qualify for most visas to the
>   US. Temporary visitors to Japan may apply for a visa, but it is more
>   difficult to qualify for a visa outside the country of permanent
>   residence.